# SQL - Select latest record based on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following table.

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+
| ID | Parent | Status |    Date    |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
|  1 |    667 | O      | 2019-09-23 |
|  1 |    667 | O      | 2019-10-01 |
|  1 |    667 | C      | 2019-10-12 |
|  1 |    667 | O      | 2019-10-31 |
| 33 |    566 | C      | 2019-09-28 |
| 33 |    566 | C      | 2019-10-03 |
| 33 |    566 | C      | 2019-10-17 |
| 33 |    566 | C      | 2019-10-23 |
| 33 |    566 | C      | 2019-10-29 |
|  2 |    667 | O      | 2019-10-01 |
|  2 |    667 | O      | 2019-10-12 |
|  2 |    667 | C      | 2019-10-31 |
| 34 |    566 | O      | 2019-10-03 |
| 34 |    566 | O      | 2019-10-17 |
| 34 |    566 | C      | 2019-10-23 |
| 34 |    566 | C      | 2019-10-29 |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
```

Now i need to find all `ID`'s in the table between `2019-10-01` and `2019-10-31` which had the status `O` during that period, and has status `C` as per the latest record.

Expected Output:

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+
| ID | Parent | Status |    Date    |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
|  2 |    667 | C      | 2019-10-31 |
| 34 |    566 | C      | 2019-10-29 |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
```

I tried querying

```sql
SELECT ID, Parent, Status, Date
FROM tabe WHERE Status='C' AND DATE >= '2019-10-01' AND Date <= '2019-10-31' AND ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM tabe WHERE Status='O' AND Date >= '2019-10-01' AND Date <= '2019-10-31'
);
```

and got the following output

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+
| ID | Parent | Status |    Date    |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
|  1 |    667 | C      | 2019-10-12 |
|  2 |    667 | C      | 2019-10-31 |
| 34 |    566 | C      | 2019-10-23 |
| 34 |    566 | C      | 2019-10-29 |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify that you want the ids.  So, you can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select id
from t
where date >= '2019-10-01' and date < '2019-11-01'
group by id
having sum( status = 'O' ) > 0 and
       max(case when status = 'C' then date end) = max(date);
```

If you actually want the original rows, you can use `JOIN`, `IN`, `EXISTS` or window functions.  For the latter:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(status = 'O') over (partition by id) as num_os,
             first_value(status) over (partition by id order by date desc) as last_status
      from t
      where date >= '2019-10-01' and date < '2019-11-01'
     ) t
where num_os > 0 and last_status = 'C';
```

Comment: I tried your first query, it worked well `select ID, Parent, max(date) from tabe where date >= '2019-10-01' and date < '2019-11-01' group by id having sum( status = 'O' ) > 0 and max(case when status = 'C' then date end) = max(date);`

Comment: I've another doubt here, consider ID: `34` the above query return its max date. What should i do to get the date it started showing `C` in the same query.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=aaf5ebae2d1c3716054166fd96317b84